# How can I attribute to an iterator the adress of another one?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to attribute to an iterator the adreess of another one +1 to go on into a string vector.Here is my code:

```
'    for(auto it:cuvinte)
    {
        int nr=1;
        incercare.clear();
        incercare.push_back(it);
        for(auto i2:cuvinte)
        {
            if(incercare.back()[incercare.back().size()-1]==i2[0])
            {
                ++nr;
                incercare.push_back(i2);
            }
            if(nr>maxim)
                {
                    maxim=nr;
                    solutie=incercare;
                }

        }'
```

I want i2 to get the adreess of it+1 to go in the right of it in the vector. Please help me.

Comment: You have to post whole code. In general in range based incantation [`for(auto el : range)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) `el` type is not an iterator over range/containter, but rather element type. In this sense, `it+1` had a quite misleading meaning IMHO.

Comment: @VictorZarzu The mistake you are making is that `it` and `i2` are not iterators. If you used real iterators it would be easy.

Comment: @VictorZarzu It depends what `cuvinte` is, which you haven't explained.

Comment: yeah, but I have vector<string> and I can not access the first element of one string with *it[0];

Comment: 'vector<string>cuvinte'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should get the job done. Just changed the starting point of innerloop.

```
for (auto it = cuvinte.begin(); it != cuvinte.end(); ++it)
{
    int nr = 1;
    incercare.clear();
    incercare.push_back(*it);
    for (auto i2 = it+1; i2 != cuvinte.end(); ++i2)
    {
        if (incercare.back()[incercare.back().size()-1] == (*i2)[0])
        {
            ++nr;
            incercare.push_back(*i2);
        }
        if (nr > maxim)
        {
            maxim = nr;
            solutie = incercare;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So here's the code above rewritten to use iterators instead of a range based for loop. I'm afraid I still don't understand what change you want to make.

```
for (auto it = cuvinte.begin(); it != cuvinte.end(); ++it)
{
    int nr = 1;
    incercare.clear();
    incercare.push_back(*it);
    for (auto i2 = cuvinte.begin(); i2 != cuvinte.end(); ++i2)
    {
        if (incercare.back()[incercare.back().size()-1] == (*i2)[0])
        {
            ++nr;
            incercare.push_back(*i2);
        }
        if (nr > maxim)
        {
            maxim = nr;
            solutie = incercare;
        }
    }
}
```